# Wildcard integer in javascript condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a section of a form that can be duplicated indefinitely, and I'm attempting to create a validation condition for it (using the ajaxForm plugin, although this aspect is relatively incidental).

The condition looks a bit like this:

```
if(formData[i].name == 'create-flight[fields][0][scheduled-departure-time]' && formData[i].value == ''){
    // Do stuff
}
```

Note the `0` in `create-flight[fields][0][scheduled-departure-time]`. This could be a `0`, a `1`, or even a `37`. Importantly I don't need to know, as the function handles everything dynamically and this condition triggers within a foreach, so every field will be checked. Is there a way to add a wildcard here? i.e. `create-flight[fields]['+any_integer+'][scheduled-departure-time]` ?

Often this would be catered for with an `or` operator, but it could be *any* number, so that's not practical.

Comment: RegExp could help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried a regex?  Try

```
formData[i].name.match(/^create-flight\[fields\]\[[0-9]+\]\[scheduled-departure-time\]$/)
```

Comment: Need the start and end delimiters

Comment: Thanks, seems regex was the obvious answer, feel a bit silly for not thinking of it! Will give this a spin!

Answer (score 0):

You can test this with a regular expression:

```
var re = new RegExp("^create-flight\[fields\]\[[0-9]+\]\[scheduled-departure-time\]$");
if (re.test(formData[i].name)) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: this will match 'create-flight[fields][scheduled-departure-time]' or create-flight[fields]-[scheduled-departure-time].  You need the escaped brackets around the 0-9 matching group, and it shouldnt have the initial hyphen. `\[[0-9]+\]`

Comment: Yes indeed, went a little too fast on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use regular expressions (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp).

I would use something like:

```
/create-flight\[fields\]\[\d+\]\[scheduled-departure-time\]/
```

So the final code should look like this:

```
var patt = new RegExp(/create-flight\[fields\]\[\d+\]\[scheduled-departure-time\]/);
if(patt.test(formData[i].name) && formData[i].value == ''){
    // Do stuff
}
```